# laravel app in iframe csrf missmatch in safari whit error status 419()

Tags: php, laravel, safari

I have an app in Laravel 10.x, due to php compatibility problems, it runs on a different domain from the one where I added the iframe.

on chrome everything works but if I try to launch the app from safari my ajax calls have a 419 response.

I have already tried to change the session.php entry

```
same_site => 'none'
```

I added

```
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true
```

to my env file, but I can't get it to work.
I've read that it's a common problem with safari but I can't find a solution.

could someone help me?

Comment: Have you checked the browser settings for allowing third party cookies? If it's disabled, try enabling it and test again. If that is the reason, you should rethink the solution since people might have that setting disabled.

Comment: I found the "prevent cross-site tracking" option enabled in the Safari settings.

once this option is disabled, the csrf works again.

Since it's a browser setting, do you recommend finding other solutions other than iframe or is there a way to exclude this control from code?